# Why the first time that i use async it will give me an empty array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, async-await, backend

I'm making an app in JS with Node.js.
I'm trying to use the async/await function.

When I execute the code below, the first time that I make a get request it gives to me an empty array, if I make a second get request, it gives to me the array fully.
Why did this happen?

````
    var sql = `SELECT * FROM Pietanza`;
    await db.query(sql, (error, result, fields)=>{
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        result.forEach(j => {
            var temp = j;
            //retrieving indicatori (spicy, vegan for example)
            sql = `SELECT indicatore FROM pietanza_indicatore WHERE pietanza = '${temp.nome}'`;
            db.query(sql, (error, result, fields)=>{
                if(error) throw error;
                temp.indicatori = new Array();
                 result.forEach(ind => {
                    temp.indicatori.push(ind.indicatore);
                    //console.log(temp);
                });
            });
            pietanze.menu.push(temp);
        });
        //console.log(pietanze);
    });
    //sends the JSON menu
    //console.log(pietanze);
    res.json(pietanze);
});```

Thank you in advance.
````

Comment: What is `db`? It looks like you're using `await`, but it's not clear that this API you're calling returns Promises. It doesn't look like it does; rather, it seems to use the callback pattern.

Comment: Don't pass a callback to a function that you expect to return a promise (that you want to `await`)

Comment: `await` is used to wait for Promises to settle, it knows nothing about every little thing that can be asynchronous in javascript, it is purely syntactic sugar for Promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `db.query` is asynchronous, but since you're using callbacks, it's unlikely that it's returning Promises, so await won't do what you're expecting. If you want to use `await`, you may have to adapt this API.

```
const query = sql => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.query(sql, (error, result, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      return reject(error);
    }

    resolve(result);
  });
});

const result = await query(`SELECT * FROM Pietanza`);

const menu = await Promise.all(result.map(temp => {
  //retrieving indicatori (spicy, vegan for example)
  const indicatori = await query(`
    SELECT indicatore
    FROM pietanza_indicatore
    WHERE pietanza = '${temp.nome}'
  `);
  return {
    ...temp,
    indicatori: indicatori.map(ind => ind.indicatore)
  };
}));

res.json({ ...pietanze, menu });
```

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing `async/await` and callbacks. That won't work, because `await` won't wait for callbacks to finish.

If you want to do it with `await` the syntax is roughly as follows (assuming the database package supports promises)

```
try {
  let outerresult = await db.query(outersql);
  ...
  for (let row of outerresult) {
     ...
     let innerresult = await db.query(innersql);
     ...
  }

} catch (error) {
  // Do the error handling
}
```

You also can't use `Array.forEach` with `async/await` because it doesn't support asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Just be careful with `await` in a for loop like this because that means you're only doing one request at a time, so if `outerresult` is large, the wait time could be large. `Promise.all` lets you await things in parallel.

Comment: @Jacob yeah you are right. But that may depend on the specific use case, which one is to prefer. Bombarding an SQL server with myriads of parallel queries may also not always be the best solution.

Comment: in the current case it may even be possible to just use a join in the outer query and get rid of the inner query.

Answer (score -1):

It's due to the nature of the **async** request you're making.
async requests will run whenever they can run, so you need to wait for them to return their values before you can use them (e.g. to loop through them and display them)

Comment: I didn't understood how to fix this problem. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: @MichaelDiMeo place `console.log` into your code at various places and see the order they print to console to better understand the nature of asynchronous code.